# Ethernet Not Working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ethernet

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on separate partition and Ethernet is not working.
Hardware - 
AMD FX - 8320E
DDR3 8GB
AMD Radeon R7 200 series

**lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2; ifconfig** -- **Output Below**

```
rahul@Ubuntu14:~$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2; ifconfig
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:e6:ca:8e  
          inet6 addr: fe80::feab:14ff:fee6:ca8e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:177 (177.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:11936 (11.9 KB)  TX bytes:11936 (11.9 KB)
```

**I'm having wifi router connected to modem and it works fine on windows.**

[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYEal.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2; ifconfig` terminal command.

Comment: I have done changes as you said in question.

Comment: So are you asking about some USB wifi dongle or an Ethetnet wired network?

Comment: I'm having ethernet connected to system and and wifi router connected to modem(i connect my phone using wifi router) 
check image link below question

Comment: It is not clear at all. How is you phone related to the question? Do you know that Ethernet is a wired connection? Do you use it? Where is it connected?

Comment: I'm just clarifying. White colored ethernet wire is connected to PC and wifi-router and from wifi-router, their is one more ethernet wire connected to modem thats how PC, WIFI router and Modem is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a new revision of `RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)`.

The generic kernel module `r8169` does not support this revision.

You can install a driver specific to this `r8168` adapter released by Realtek.

Download these files to your Ubuntu Home directory

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.041.00-1_all.deb
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb

then run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb r8168-dkms*.deb
```

Reboot and test the Ethernet.

Comment: Hey @Pilot6 it's working.Thanks. Can you explain what was wrong and how these files helped me.?

Comment: OK. I will update my answer.